# How frequently are ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGEDs sent, in real devices?

Tags: android, batterymanager

In the emulator, if I set `power capacity` to a value different from the current value, my `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive` is called with the new value.  (I've registered with `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`.)

In a real device, whose battery is discharging from 100 to 20 percent over a period of a few days, will my `onReceive` method be called:

- exactly 80 times,
- more than 80 times or
- fewer than 80 times?

---

Re: possible duplicate question - I'm also concerned about the handler not being called often enough.  I've also not made the mistake of registering a broadcast receiver from within another broadcast receiver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ACTION\_BATTERY\_CHANGED firing like crazy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624882/action-battery-changed-firing-like-crazy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the most common behavior is to send exactly 80 messages, but some devices will send more or fewer. This varies dramatically among real devices, and so it will have to be benchmarked for the specific devices you'll be using, or handled in the general case.

For most devices I've worked with, `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` will be sent exactly 80 times in that scenario. (The intent will also be sent when the device is plugged and unplugged.)

However, for a small number of models, the message is sent every time the battery temperature changes. This can happen very frequently, depending particularly on how much processing the tablet is doing. I'm working from memory, but I believe the Verizon Ellipsis 7 tablet behaves like this.

Also, some devices apparently send messages fewer than once per 1% change in battery level. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624882/action-battery-changed-firing-like-crazy) is an example of more frequent messages, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189218/detect-changing-battery-state-at-every-percentage-in-android/10190055#10190055) is an example of fewer messages.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not guarantee that, for eg. between battery discharge from 100 to 80%, system does not guarantee it will send 20 events once per percent discharge of battery. Many parameters are into consideration. You can find simple explanation  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624882/action-battery-changed-firing-like-crazy?lq=1)

If you want to keep track of battery discharge then do pooling timely. Number of events from system may vary from device to device.