# Not getting updated Battery State in BroadcastReceiver [android]

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, batterymanager

I have a broadcast receiver for ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED registered in manifest.
When I connect power this is getting invoked and onReceive is working just fine.

In onReceive i am retrieving battery charging status using method given in google docs as follows:

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);

boolean isCharging = false;
if(status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL){
      isCharging = true;
}
```

This method is giving me correct isCharging value for first time i connect the charger. When I unplug and again plug it back I am getting false for isCharging.

I am using Motorola XT1068 and facing above issue.
The same code is working fine for One Plus Two.

Can someone please please guide me as I wanna make my app work in all phones thats why developing on min API 10.

From THIRD point in ans on ([Detect Changing Battery state at every percentage in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189218/detect-changing-battery-state-at-every-percentage-in-android)) i also believe the same to be a problem. But I badly need a work around.

Thanks in advance.
Edit:I know that as my receiver is registered for Battery Connected and hence there is no point in checking if its charging BUT i have other receivers which are not registered for this and still checks for battery status regularly.

Comment: I know that as my receiver is registered for Battery Connected and hence there is no point in checking if its charging BUT i have other receivers which are not registered for this and still checks for battery status regularly.